# Is there a good XMPP (Jabber) library for Arduino?

Tags: arduino-yun

I have a few sensors plugged in and getting some data from them. I want to use XMPP protocol to push the sensor data to my main server. Is there a good XMPP library available which I can use?

Answer (score 1):

A quick search pulls up https://github.com/adamvr/XMPPArduino which hasn't been touched since it was first created five years ago, and may or may not work. XMPP is a very heavy protocol that is very burdensome for a microcontroller to try and run. You could try and get the above library to work, or I would recommend one of the following alternatives:

- Load an XMPP client onto the OpenWRT side of the Yun and send commands from the Yun to control it. (<strike>Although glancing through the list of packages, there does not appear to be a pre-existing one. So this might not be an option unless you are up for cross compiling one.</strike> Looks like there is at least one: BitlBee via https://github.com/arduino/openwrt-packages-yun)
- Have the Arduino communicate using a lighter weight protocol (e.g. HTTP or MQTT) to another server or application that you write, which in turn sends your XMPP message using a readily available library.